# Checking if textarea is empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Here's my code:

```
if ($('#inputName').val() && $('#inputEmail').val() && $('#inputInstrument').val() && $('#inputFee').val() $('#message').val() != '')
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('fill in all fields');
    }
```

If I take out the last condition (`#message`), it works fine, but with it in I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="includes/data.php" method="POST" id="findmusicians">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control required" minlength="1" id="inputName">
            <div id="hidden"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="email" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail">
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Telephone</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="inputTelephone" class="form-control" id="inputTelephone">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputInstrument" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Instrument(s)</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" name="inputInstrument" class="form-control" id="inputInstrument">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputFee" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Fee</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" name="inputFee" class="form-control" id="inputFee">
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="col-sm-3 control-label">* Message</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="3" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block" style="text-align: left;">Please include as much information as possible including repertoire, rehearsal/performance times and venues.</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <button id="findmusicians-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit request</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5px">
    <span id="result" class="text-success"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you've missed out the && before the last condition check. `if ($('#inputName').val() && $('#inputEmail').val() && $('#inputInstrument').val() && $('#inputFee').val() && $('#message').val() != '')`

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just adding my comment as an answer.

The problem is that you've missed out the `&&` before the last condition check.

```
if ($('#inputName').val() && $('#inputEmail').val() && $('#inputInstrument').val() && $('#inputFee').val() && $('#message').val() != '')
```

Although that works, you may want to trim() and check the textarea content length.

```
($('#message').val().trim().length > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot && before the last condition as source.rar mentioned.

Also this isn't the correct way to check that textarea is empty. $('#message').val() != ''

Might be someone type spaces.. so first trim the value and then check..

```
if ($.trim($('#message').val()).length > 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed **&&** before last condition.

```
 $('#findmusicians-submit').click(function(e){
    if ($('#inputName').val()!= '' && $('#inputEmail').val()!= '' && $('#inputInstrument').val()!= '' && $('#inputFee').val()!= '' && $('#message').val() != '')
        {
            alert('success');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('fill in all fields');
        }
 });
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9W4Wa/

Answer (score 0):

so instead you can do this:

```
var inputVals = $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputInstrument, #inputFee, #message')
if(inputVals.val() != '')
```

or:

```
var inputVals = $('input[id*="input"], #message')
if(inputVals.val() != '')
```